Unable to open chrome://apps/ using Python script
I am trying to open the Chrome Apps page (chrome://apps/) using a Python script on my Windows machine. I've tried several methods, including using the subprocess module and the webbrowser module, but none seem to work. The Chrome browser opens successfully, but the Chrome Apps page does not load.
Here's the code I've tried:
import subprocess

def open_chrome_apps():
    chrome_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    apps_url = "chrome://apps/"
    command = f'"{chrome_path}" "{apps_url}"'
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

open_chrome_apps()

import webbrowser

def open_chrome_apps():
    apps_url = "chrome://apps/"
    webbrowser.open(apps_url)

open_chrome_apps()


There are no error messages for 1st code but 2nd one gets the below exceptions I tried with Microsoft Edge and got the same exception.
enter image description here
I've verified that chrome://apps/ works fine when entered manually in the address bar of the Chrome browser.
I'm using Python 3.10 on Windows 10, and Version 123.0.6312.107 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong or provide a workaround to open the Chrome Apps page using a Python script?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
open the Chrome Apps page (chrome://apps/) using a Python script

This question that remained unanswered for 7 years probably indicates there's no way to open chrome:// URLs from the command line.
EDIT: I just came across this and accordingly, the fact that custom protocols are not startable by command line could likely be a form of security protection.
